# Routes file issues with Passport

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, routes, passport.js

I'm using NodeJS, Express, and PassportJS to build a web application. I'm having a problem with one of my routes which I can't make any sense out of. When I have:

```
...
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));
...
```

Everything seems to work fine. But when I change that to:

```
...
app.get('/auth/facebook',
  function(req, res) {
    passport.authenticate('facebook');
  });
...
```

It hangs? Am I missing something on the app.get function? I want to be able to do this because I want to make the path a little more dynamic where I determine what passport authenticates. For example:

```
...
app.get('/auth/:provider',
  function(req, res) {
    passport.authenticate(req.params.provider);
  });
...
```

Where provider could be `facebook`, `twitter`, or `google`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

passport.authenticate is middleware, take a gander at the source: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js

passport.authenticate('facebook') returns a function that takes the req, res, next parameters from express and handles them.

so:

```
app.get('/auth/:provider',
  function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate(req.params.provider)(req, res, next);
  });
```

is what you need.